# Particle "ter" in german surnames such as Marc-André ter Stegen. Does it mean something?

Tags: meaning, particle, person-names

I read the football news and I have a non-football question now.

Does the particle "ter" mean something in a such kind of german names as Marc-André ter Stegen?

Are there other particles?

Comment: It's actually a Dutch surname. German citizens occasionally have Dutch (or French, Polish…) surnames but the question would perhaps be more appropriate on the equivalent Dutch-language site (if there is such a thing?)

Comment: @Annoyed, there is no dutch SO site unfortunately.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

'ter' is a particle from the Netherlands, which means 'zur' in German.

With that in mind, a [quick search](http://www.wordsense.eu/stegen/) reveals that the dutch word 'Stegen' can be [translated](https://translate.google.com/?source=osdd#auto/de/steeg) to 'Gasse' in German, which makes his name something like Marc-André zur Gasse.

It seems that 'ter' would be used to say where someone is coming from, independent from social status. In our example, Marc-André is from an alleyway.

You can find a whole list of particles used in names (royal and non-royal) on [wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adelspr%C3%A4dikat#Niederlande)